# Angular 2 - Simpler to handle HTTP responses

Tags: angular

Working with Angular 2. I have a component and service. In the component I make request to get a list of companies. It then calls the Service to get the companies through an API. On response the companies are stored in a service variable called companies. In addition an observable is announced called announceCompanyData(). The component listens to the event and the request the service for the data and refreshes the UI.

I feel this a complicated way to handle HTTP response. Is there are simpler way to do this in Angular 2? Here is my code is below:

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class CompanyCommService {
  private companyDataAnnouncedSource = new Subject();
  companyDataAnnouncedSource$ = this.companyDataAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  company: any;
  url: string = APIDOMAIN;
  constructor(public authHttp: AuthHttp, public http: Http) { }  
  announceCompanyData() {
    this.companyDataAnnouncedSource.next();
  }
  getData(i) {
    if (i==='companies') {
      return this.companies;
    }
  }
  getCompanies() {
    console.log('JWT');
    let headers = new Headers();
    let data = null;
    let id = 'fc65c467-336c-4271-85c3-278e419ac39d';
    var token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    console.log(token);
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token); 
    this.http.get(this.url+ '/companies', {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => { 
        this.companies = data;
        this.announceCompanyData();  
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => console.log('Request Complete')
    );
  }  
}
```

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-company-directory',
  templateUrl: './company-directory.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-directory.component.css']
})
export class CompanyDirectoryComponent implements OnInit {
  companies: any = null; 
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private navCommService: NavCommService,private companyCommService: CompanyCommService) { 
    this.subscription = companyCommService.companyDataAnnouncedSource$.subscribe(
      status => {
      this.companies = this.companyCommService.getData('companies');
      console.log('New Companies Data',this.companies); 
    })   
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  requestData(): void {
    this.companyCommService.getCompanies();
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out the response from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040322/extract-data-from-json-response-in-a-angular-2-service/39040632#39040632

Answer (score 1):

Instead of announcing everytime to all the components subscribing to the observable you could just declare a method in service of type observable and subscribe to this method in the component so whenever you call the getCompanies method after it has completed the request it will return the data to component

**In Service**

```
getCompanies() (): Observable<Companies[]> { 
     return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl).map(this.extractData)
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  if(res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
    throw new Error('Bad response status ' + res.status);
   }

  let body = res.json();
  /* here you can save body in any global variable*/
  return body.data || {};
}
```

**In the Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.companyCommService.getCompanies( companies => this.companies = companies , error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks alot simpler. If I want to store companies within a service variable as well send it to component what would be the best way?

Comment: here `this.extractData` is a function (i have added this in answer) you can use this to store the value.

Comment: Hi Gave it a go but it gives an error on the component side. Excluding the getHeroes() typo I get an error supplied parameters do not match any signature call target

Comment: there is one more typo error replace `getCompanies() ()` to ``getCompanies()`